# Custom Module not showing up

Tags: 8

Playing around with Drupal 8 and trying to create a custom module with a custom block:

I have a module.info.yaml file:

```
name: Custom Module
description: Description Here
package: Custom Module
type: module
core: 8.x

dependencies:
  - block
```

I have a src/Plugin/CustomBlock/CustomBlock.php file:

```
<?php

/**
 * Provides a 'Custom' Block
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "custom_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Custom Block"),
 * )
 */

namespace Drupal\custom_block\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

class CustomBlock extends BlockBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    return array(
      '#markup' => $this->t('Hello, World!'),
    );
  }
}
```

The module is in /modules/custom/module. I have installed contrib modules in /modules/contrib with no issue.

If I go to the Extend page, my module is not listed.

Please let me know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typo on the module file name:

```
module.info.yaml
```

Should be

```
module.info.yml
```

Comment: Yep. D8 only requires `.info.yml` file in order to show up on the module's page.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I think I'm mistaken, sorry!  For now, just putting this note into the comment -- when I have a more definitive answer, I'll update again.

---

FWIW, with Drupal core 8.7.7, our custom module didn't show on /admin/modules until I added the new `core_version_requirement` key to `mymodule.info.yml`, i.e.

```
core_version_requirement: '^8'
```

For now, I kept the old `core: 8.x` line in there, too, b/c I'm unsure whether it's good/bad/neutral to have both -- I think it's still being decided, tbh.  Speaking of which, there's a change record and a ton of issue threads (active and completed) you can check out to learn more, if you wish:

- [8.7.7 release notes](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.7.7) excerpt:

  > **Core versioning support in *.info.yml files**
  >   Drupal 8.7.7 introduces a new `core_version_requirement` key to
  >   `*.info.yml` files, allowing contributed modules to specify specific versions for Drupal core compatiblity, as well as to indicate that
  >   they are compatible with both Drupal 8 and the forthcoming Drupal 9
  >   release. See the change record for more details.
- [Change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/3070687) (mentioned in that excerpt)
- [Main issue thread for this functionality](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2313917) -- plus all the related
  issues listed on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure your web server has file permissions to the module.

Answer (score -1):

Web server permissions may indeed be the issue, especially if everything else seems fine.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/security-in-drupal/securing-file-permissions-and-ownership

I constantly run this set of commands because my Windows ftp client sets ownership to my-user:my-user.  Your web server might not be apache.

(requires a symlink to your drupal root folder from the server root)

```
cd /drupal9
sudo chown -R my-user:apache .
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 750 '{}' \;
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 640 '{}' \;
cd web/sites
sudo find . -type d -name files -exec chmod 770 '{}' \;
for d in ./*/files
do
   sudo find $d -type d -exec chmod 770 '{}' \;
   sudo find $d -type f -exec chmod 660 '{}' \;
done
```